# Navigation Controller count 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, count

```
NSLog(@"Views in hierarchy: %lu",
    (unsigned long)[navigationController.viewControllers count]);
```

I got the answer 0 in the `NSLog`

Comment: We need to know a lot more to be able to answer this for you.

Comment: You should update this to explain what your question actually is, what you're trying to do, etc. - the usual stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just print it as,

```
NSLog(@"Views in hierarchy: %d", [navigationController.viewControllers count]);
```

Comment: Should really have been a comment IMHO.